# gitlab container proxy pass by nginx doesn't work with push request

Tags: docker, nginx, ssh, gitlab

I have 3 containers on my docker. and I want to have gitlab as a subdomain.
my gitlab container ports are:

```
443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10022->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10080->80/tcp
```

gitlab container has created with this command:

```
docker run --detach --name gitlab --restart=always\
    --publish 10022:22 --publish 10080:80 \
    --network nginx_network \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --env 'EXTERNAL_URL=https://develop.domain.com' \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
    gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

my nginx config is:

```
upstream isa_fire {
    server isa_fire:8000;
}
upstream gitlab {
    server gitlab:80;
}
upstream gedata {
    server geoserver:8080;
}



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://isa_fire;
        proxy_redirect  off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }


    location /static/ {
        alias /isa_fire/static/;
    }

    location /files/ {
        alias /isa_fire/;
    }
    
}

server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   develop.domain.com www.develop.domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://gitlab;
    proxy_redirect  off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

  }
}

server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   geoserver.domain.com www.geoserver.domain.com;

  location / {
        proxy_pass  http://gedata;

  }

}


client_max_body_size 240M;
```

every things works good with browser on my gitlab. but when i try to push:

```
git push -u origin master
```

face with this error after some minutes:

*ssh: connect to host develop.domain.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists*

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to expose Port 22 too, if you want to use SSH.

So that means your nginx config must be extended with a second server which listens on port 22 and proxy passes it to your gitlab docker container.

Port 22 must be also forwarded/opened in your router settings!

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this ,

1. Change docker host ssh port from 22 to something else, then create gitlab container with these ports instead, 22:22 ,10080:80, 443
2. Or you can edit .git/config file of your project , in address add port 10022 at the end of url

Btw you can pull and push using http(s) url of the project and leave ssh